# async/await on many forms ping function

Tags: vb.net

I have some problem and couldn't see so far what i am doing wrong. My application user can open some form multiple times and within each of it i want to make ping time to time to some remote host then show status on status bar, therefore to not block main thread and ui i decided to go `asyn/await`. Unfortunetly within `'DoWork'` method `'StartNew'` is highlited within this line:

```
Await Task.Factory.StartNew(IsDestinationReachable(IPAddress))
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error BC36645 Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) in method 'Public
>   Overloads Function StartNew(Of TResult)([function] As Func(Of
>   TResult)) As Task(Of TResult)' cannot be inferred from these
>   arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this
>   error.

And by the way is it right way i am doing it? Check my code below:

```
Public Class FrmDrukujEtykiete

    Private Property IPAddress As String
    Private WithEvents mytimer As Timer

    Sub New(ipaddress As String)
        InitializeComponent()
        AddHandler mytimer.Tick, AddressOf dowork
        mytimer.Interval = 6000
        mytimer.Enabled = True
        mytimer.Start()
        Me.IPAddress = ipaddress
    End Sub

    Public Async Sub dowork(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim MMOO As Task(Of Boolean) = Await Task.Factory.StartNew(IsDestinationReachable(IPAddress))
        If MMOO.Result Then
            tsPingResultIcon.BackColor = Color.Green
            tsPingResultIcon.Text = "OK - Remote ip reachable"
        Else
            tsPingResultIcon.BackColor = Color.Red
            tsPingResultIcon.Text = "NOT OK - Remote ip NOT reachable"
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function IsDestinationReachable(ByVal hostnameOrAddress As String) As Boolean
        Dim reachable As Boolean = False
        Try
            reachable = My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable AndAlso My.Computer.Network.Ping(hostnameOrAddress)

        Catch pingException As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException
        Catch genericNetworkException As System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationException

            ' Fail silently and return false
        End Try
        Return reachable
    End Function

End Class
```

**EDIT:**
i think i was able to make it happen - one thing which still considering me is why when user opening new form before it show up its about 4 seconds... second thing is it correct - i mean can you check my code is there any wrong task conception usage? Generally working...

```
Public Class FrmDrukujEtykiete

    Private etykieta As New Etykieta
    Private Property IPAddress As String
    Private WithEvents mytimer As New Timer

    Sub New(ipaddress As String)
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.IPAddress = ipaddress
        AddHandler mytimer.Tick, AddressOf dowork
        mytimer.Interval = 6000
        mytimer.Enabled = True
        mytimer.Start()
        DoSomethingElse()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DoSomethingElse()
        For i = 1 To 100000
            '  Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(i)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnWyjdz_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnWyjdz.Click
        Close()
    End Sub

    Public Async Sub dowork(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim tsk As Task(Of Boolean) = Task.Factory.StartNew(Of Boolean)(Function()
                                                                            '--Run lenghty task
                                                                            Dim reachable = False
                                                                            Try
                                                                                reachable = My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable AndAlso My.Computer.Network.Ping(IPAddress)

                                                                            Catch pingException As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException
                                                                            Catch genericNetworkException As System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationException

                                                                                ' Fail silently and return false
                                                                            End Try
                                                                            Return reachable
                                                                        End Function)

        Await tsk

        ListBox2.Items.Add("a teraz zmiana")

        If tsk.Result Then
            tsPingResultIcon.BackColor = Color.Green
            tsPingResultIcon.Text = "OK - Remote ip reachable"
        Else
            tsPingResultIcon.BackColor = Color.Red
            tsPingResultIcon.Text = "NOT OK - Remote ip NOT reachable"
        End If

    End Sub

    Public Function IsDestinationReachable(ByVal hostnameOrAddress As String)
        Dim reachable = False
        Try
            reachable = My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable AndAlso My.Computer.Network.Ping(hostnameOrAddress)

        Catch pingException As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException
        Catch genericNetworkException As System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationException

            ' Fail silently and return false
        End Try
        Return reachable
    End Function



End Class
```

Comment: Try: `Task.Factory.StartNew(IsDestinationReachable(IPAddress), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default)`

Comment: Your title makes it look like you are asking the same question again.  You might want to try to differentiate it better from your previous question.

Comment: can you please take a look on my main topic -EDIT section i think i figure it out - what do you think? Generally looks like its working but can anyone check the code?

Comment: Don't know about the rest of your code, but that line should probably be `Dim MMOO As Boolean = Await Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() IsDestinationReachable(IPAddress))`.

Comment: @Mark yes i can also make like this :  Dim tsk As Task(Of Boolean) = Task.Factory.StartNew(Of Boolean)(Function() IsDestinationReachable(IPAddress))

Comment: this is according to what i did in my EDIT - can you please take a look do you think its ok (generally now workinig)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your updated code is not typically how you would use `Async`/`Await`.  More usual would be something like:

```
Public Async Sub dowork(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim isReachable As Boolean = Await Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() IsDestinationReachable(IPAddress))
    If isReachable Then
        tsPingResultIcon.BackColor = Color.Green
        tsPingResultIcon.Text = "OK - Remote ip reachable"
    Else
        tsPingResultIcon.BackColor = Color.Red
        tsPingResultIcon.Text = "NOT OK - Remote ip NOT reachable"
    End If
End Sub
```

The `Await` suspends the method until the task completes and then returns the result of the task, so there is no need to hold onto the `Task` object and use `.Result`.  While the method is suspended, execution of the non-`Await`ing code continues on the main thread, and the method is resumed on the main thread when the async method completes.

However, since network IO is naturally async, you would be better off using the [`Ping.SendPingAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159414%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`.  That would be something like this (untested code):

```
Public Async Sub dowork(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim isReachable As Boolean = Await IsDestinationReachable(IPAddress)
    If isReachable Then
        tsPingResultIcon.BackColor = Color.Green
        tsPingResultIcon.Text = "OK - Remote ip reachable"
    Else
        tsPingResultIcon.BackColor = Color.Red
        tsPingResultIcon.Text = "NOT OK - Remote ip NOT reachable"
    End If
End Sub

Public Async Function IsDestinationReachable(ByVal hostnameOrAddress As String) As Boolean
    Dim reachable As Boolean = False
    Try
        If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then
            Dim pinger As Ping = New Ping()
            Dim result As PingReply = Await pinger.SendPingAsync(hostnameOrAddress) 
            reachable = result.Status = IPStatus.Success
        End If
    Catch pingException As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException
    Catch genericNetworkException As System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationException
        ' Fail silently and return false
    End Try
    Return reachable
End Function
```

Comment: on this line:  reachable = Await pinger.SendPingAsync(hostnameOrAddress) i am getting error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error BC30311 Value of type 'PingReply' cannot be converted to 'Boolean'.

Comment: @JohnDoe Ah... that would be the untested part... sorry about that.  I've updated the code - try it now (still untested!).

Comment: correct me if i am wrong - when code will reach line where await is placed and lets say operation there would take some long time then the code will leave dowork method and will not go next lines there (If isReachable Then ..) it will go out do code which is next in main thread and go back to await when await method (isdestinationreachable) ends then it will go If isReachable Then. Am i right with what i just wrote?

Comment: could you be so kind an answer

Comment: @JohnDoe  Sorry, only just 8am here! You are correct. The `Await` will suspend the current method and the main thread will continue executing the code that isn't `Await`ing... in your case after the call to `dowork` in the `Tick` event handler.  Once the ping returns (in the final code example) execution of `IsDestinationReachable` will resume on the main thread (async code is not necessarily multi-threaded, which is one of the benefits, although `Task.Factory.StartNew` will start a new thread).

Comment: just have one more ask - i just moved from 4.6.1 framework to 4.0 and i am facing two errors regarding your code could you be so kind and look on it in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048217/await-requires-that-the-type-task-have-a-suitable-getawaiter-method