# Await requires that the type Task have a suitable GetAwaiter method

Tags: vb.net

I just move my working app to framework 4.0 from 4.6.1 and i have the only one problem. The error message i get as in subject. I also have second error:

```
SendPingAsync is not a member of 'Ping'
```

The subject error appears within method below on this line highlited:

```
Await IsDestinationReachable(IPAddress)
```

Method:

```
 Public Async Sub Pinguj(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim isReachable As Boolean = Await IsDestinationReachable(IPAddress)
        ListBox2.Items.Add("a teraz zmiana")
        If isReachable Then
            tsPingResultIcon.BackColor = Color.Green
        Else
            tsPingResultIcon.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub
```

Second error appear in below method on this line:

```
pinger.SendPingAsync(hostnameOrAddress)
```

method:

```
 Public Async Function IsDestinationReachable(ByVal hostnameOrAddress As String) As Task(Of Boolean)
        Dim reachable As Boolean = False
        Try
            If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then
                Dim pinger As Ping = New Ping()
                Dim result As PingReply = Await pinger.SendPingAsync(hostnameOrAddress)
                reachable = result.Status = IPStatus.Success
            End If
        Catch pingException As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException
        Catch genericNetworkException As System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationException
            ' Fail silently and return false
        End Try
        Return reachable
    End Function
```

Comment: `Async` support was officially added in the .NET 4.5 timeframe, and although there is some support for using it with .NET 4.0 using the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) package and the VS2012+ compilers, most of the async methods in the framework require .NET 4.5+.  For .NET 4.0, you will probably be back to `Task.Factory.StartNew` or something like that to wrap the non-async method calls.  Some more info [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2012/10/22/using-asyncawait-without-net-framework-4-5/).