# .NET Framework 4 VB.Net Call an API

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, api

I am working in an "old" VB.Net application. I wish to make a call to an API, check if I got a `404`, parse the JSON result and all the other usual things you can do with an API call.

What is the cleanest way of doing this? I thought I can use the [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) class, but I can't apparently! VS 2017 is not giving me the option of adding `System.Net.Http` as an Import.

**CODE**

Right now I'm doing this which seems messy.

```
Public Function GetUserInfo(ByVal authTokenBytes As Byte()) As WebPayWS.GetUserInfoResult
  Dim token As New token
  token.token1 = authTokenBytes
  Dim userInformation As GetUserInfoResult = _myService.GetUserInfo(token)
  If AccountExists(userInformation.accountno) Then
    Dim response As String = GetAccountInfoFromApi(userInformation.accountno)
  End If
  Return userInformation
End Function

Private Function GetAccountInfoFromApi(accountno As String) As String
  Dim accountInformationUrl As String = "URL"
  Dim webClient As WebClient = New WebClient()
  Return webClient.DownloadString(New Uri(accountInformationUrl))
End Function
```

Am I stuck with `WebClient`? If yes, how do I check for a `404` using WebClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it in an exception with the WebClient [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915785/webclient-downloadstringurl-when-this-url-returns-a-404-page-how-can-i-skip-t)

```
Private Function GetAccountInfoFromApi(accountno As String) As String
Dim accountInformationUrl As String = "URL"
Dim webClient As WebClient = New WebClient()
'Return webClient.DownloadString(New Uri(accountInformationUrl))
Dim retString As String

Try 
    retString = webClient.DownloadString(New Uri(accountInformationUrl))

   Catch ex As WebException
    If ex.Status = WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError AndAlso ex.Response IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim resp = DirectCast(ex.Response, HttpWebResponse)
        If resp.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound Then
            ' HTTP 404
            'other steps you want here
        End If
    End If
    'throw any other exception - this should not occur
    Throw
End Try
Return retString

End Function
```

Comment: So it is true, I cannot use HttpClient in .NET Framework v4. Thanks @JimmySmith

Comment: No, it is not true.

Comment: Yes, based on the 2nd part of the question - you cannot use HttpClient until 4.5.  But if you need to go further with this, I recommend the HttpWebRequest/Response classes, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference first

- Right click on project
- Add...

  - Reference...
- Browse
- *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\System.Net.Http.dll*
- Ok

[image]

Now, you can import

```
Imports System.Net.Http
```

You can also use NuGet, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13668810/832052

Comment: hmm, I thought VS usually does this automatically. I never had to do this when working in C# / Framework 4.5

Comment: it sounds like I can't use the `httpClient.GetAsync(url)` in .NET Framework 4? I'm getting the same error as this person https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048217/await-requires-that-the-type-task-have-a-suitable-getawaiter-method